# Is it haram to take a "loan" knowing for blocked account for education?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, money

As many of you will probably know, when you need to get a student VISA, you need to have a fixed amount of money in your blocked account. For example for Germany, you must have €11,208 and for UK, £1,023 per month (for up to 9 months) (according to the websites of the two countries).

In my country, what happens sometimes is that people ask for a loan (of sorts) from people who can afford such amounts. The process goes like this- you ask for a loan and the person lending this money to you will open a joint account with you. This account is there just for the proof of bank statement which shows that you do indeed have this money. In the meantime, (until that person is able to withdraw his money from the account), all you have to end up paying is a percentage of the total amount you were loaned. It could be anything like 5-10% per week. Once your VISA process is done, you will return that money and you will have ended up paying a fraction of what it would have otherwise cost you.

I was wondering, is this legal/halal? Because 2 flags were raised to me about this:

1. Falsification of documents since you are technically not telling the truth about your bank statement when applying for the VISA process.
2. The percentage you are paying over money that you were loaned.

Please advice, thank you.